# Python flask flash message exception remains after restarting

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a small flask app where I had something like this:

```
@app.route('/bye')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('Adiós')
    return redirect('/index')
```

Needless to say when I ran the application and I navigated to '/bye' it gave me a UnicodeDecodeError. Well, now it gives me the same unicodedecodeerror on every page that extends the base template (which renders the messages) even after restarting the application. and always with the same dump() despite removing that flash in the source code. All I can think of is what the crap? Help please.

Well I had to restart my *computer* to clear the stupid session cache or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that flash() actually creates a session called session['_flashes']. See this code [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/helpers.py#L384). So you will probably have to either:

```
clear/delete the cookie
```

OR

```
session.pop('_flashes', None)
```

Comment: Thanks, was searching so long and was so desperate, lost about 5 hours... even though the error was fixed long time ago.

Comment: @codegeek the link needs to be updated, https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/helpers.py#L384

Answer (score 0):

Flask flashing stores the messages in a session cookie until they are succesfully "consumed".
If you get a UnicodeDecodeError (https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError) in this case the messages is not consumed, so you get the error again and again.

My solution was to delete the cookie from the browser

Since I had the problem when using localization, I solved the cause now by installing my translation object like:

```
trans = gettext.GNUTranslations(...)
trans.install(unicode=True)
```

and having UTF-8 encoding in my python source files and `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"` in the translation file (.pot)

Answer (score 0):

You're using an non ascii string "adiós", so you need to ensure that python will process strings as unicode, not as ascii.

Add this to the header of your python file. This will tell the compiler that your file contains utf8 strings

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

so your code will be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from flask import Flask
app = Flask()

@app.route('/bye') 
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('Adiós')
    return redirect('/index')
```